# Firebase auth onCreate add custom user data to Realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a React Native application with Firebase for my backend. Firebase authentication is used for the user creation, and whenever a user is created, I also store custom user data in the Realtime database. For this, I am using a Firebase cloud function (Javascript):

```
exports.createCustomUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const email = user.email;
  const userId = user.uid;
  const body = {
    // The default values for a user
    userId,
    username: "",
    nickname: "",
    activityDuration: "2",
    isPumping: false,
    email: email,
    position: "",
  };
  return admin.database().ref(`/users/${userId}`).set(body);
});
```

If I understand it correctly, it seems like the `onCreate()` method happens after the auth user has been created, not simultaneously. Is there a way to create the custom user simultaneously to the Auth user?

If this is not possible: My problem occurs right after the user signs up. When the authentication user (and the token) is created, the user is redirected to my homescreen, where I am returning JSX that includes certain information from the custom user, like so: `<Text>{customUser.activityDuration}</Text>`. The problem is that for the few moments it takes for the onCreate method to complete, `customUser` is `null`, and the call for activityDuration returns an error.

What would be the best practices to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - Cloud Functions always run **after** the event occurs that triggers them.  This behavior can't be changed.  You can't make the creation of a user successful only if your function is successful.

What you can do instead is set up a database listener at the location in the database that's expected to be written after the function complete.  Your code should have the UID of the newly created user, and you can use that to build the location to query that should be populated after the function completes.  Your listener will trigger when the data first becomes available, and your app can continue from there.

This is very similar to what I recommend in my article about [offloading work to Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07), except my example uses Firestore.